# How to do a parent/child database 'roll-up'?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

How do you properly go about rolling up and selecting all users for each parent company until there are no more parent companies?

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and I need to check if there is a @ParentID then select all the users for that company, if there is a @ParentID on that company do the same thing, ad infinity?

Thanks. I am completely new to Rollups but am just trying something like the below to get the basic query idea started.

```
USE [DB]

DECLARE @UserName VARCHAR(250) = 'crusher@abc.com'
DECLARE @ParentID INT = -1

WHILE (@ParentID <> 0)
BEGIN
    SELECT @ParentID = CASE 
            WHEN ParentCompanyID IS NULL
                THEN 0
            ELSE ParentCompanyID
            END
    FROM User2Company a
    LEFT JOIN dbo.CompanyInfo b ON a.CompanyID = b.CompanyID
    LEFT JOIN dbo.widgets ON a.companyid = widgets.companyid
    WHERE a.UserName = @UserName

    PRINT @ParentID
END

    --SELECT * FROM CompanyInfo
    --WHERE CompanyID = 100274
    --SELECT *
    --FROM CompanyInfo
    --WHERE CompanyID = 100273
```

The commented code is just a hypothetical example of where the original query found a parent CompanyID of 100274... then THAT company found a parent CompanyID of 100273... until ultimately CompanyID 100273 had a ParentCompanyID of 0 in it's column.

HOw is this typically done?

DESIRED Output from the first query might look like this:

```
100274
100273
0
```

At which point I would fetch all user's from those company id's.

Comment: Google "Recursive CTE"

Comment: "WHILE (@ParentID <> 0)
BEGIN"                 Please unlearn this as soon as you can.

Comment: @granadaCoder yes, that is what I am doing here.. this wont see the light of day.. I am trying to get the IDEA across as a junior sql developer - so I can learn to do it CORRECTLY. Please feel free to provide an answer. ty.

Comment: Ok...good that it is only for getting the idea across.  Post DDL, inserts for sample data...and desired results........for your best chance of getting solid answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's typically done with a recursive CTE:

```
;WITH
    tmp AS
    (
        SELECT  CompanyID,
                ParentCompanyID
        FROM    CompanyInfo
        WHERE   CompanyID = 100274
        UNION ALL
        SELECT      com.CompanyID,
                    com.ParentCompanyID
        FROM        CompanyInfo com
        INNER JOIN  tmp         tmp ON com.CompanyID = tmp.ParentCompanyID -- This is the recursive part
    )

SELECT * FROM tmp
```

And as others have said, avoid using loops in SQL Server. If you have to use loop, 99% of the time you are not using SQL Server properly.

Comment: Yep that's how we do it too. In fact we replaced several hundred lines of code per import  when recursive cte's came in by using them instead of the old awkward way that SQL Server 2000 made us do it. And it was faster too.